# Corrupted nav-menu?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, menus, taxonomy, terms

I am currently debugging a WP install with lots of plugins and Avada theme (Fusion core, Fusion Builder)

The thing is I can't edit the current Menu.
When I select an item and add it, the spinner pops, unpops, and nothing more happens actually.

I digged a little and tried to delete all terms and taxonomies in database but now. I can't create nav-menu because it is created with term_id 0.
Even with wp-cli, wp create menu 'test' says :
`Success: Created menu 0.` with each new invocation of the command with different menu names.

What is wrong? Anyone has tips to reinitialize menu datas ?

Comment: You can better contact the theme make on the themeforest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue.
This was due to the lost of indexes, primary keys and auto_increment feature in my database structure due to export/import database actions.
With bad export options, the indexes and primary keys at one point, weren't re-created during import and so on....

Always export your database with right structure options.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you deleted some terms and/or taxonomies related to menus. You need to get those back into the database.

Easiest solution is if you took a database backup before removing those terms, as is best practice, just restore your database. Or if the host provides automated backups, use one of those.

If you don't have any database backup, this gets a bit off-topic into more specific theme setup, but generally speaking you should switch to a default theme (i.e. Twenty Seventeen) and then try switching back to your desired theme. If that doesn't resolve the issue, you may need to start from scratch on a new WP install, export the content from the old site, import it into the new site, and manually configure all the theme settings. It's possible that if you have a fresh WP install and you copy its `wp_term_taxonomy` table into your current install, that may help.